# Unable to launch turtlebot_dashboard

Tags: ros, turtlebot, turtlebot-dashboard

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am able to ssh into my turtlebot and run the start/stop services, but I can not bring up the turtlebot dashboard.

Input:
rosrun turtlebot_dashboard turtlebot_dashboard&

Output:
[rospack] couldn't find package [turtlebot_dashboard]

What is the problem? I feel like I may have inporperly installed the turtlebot ISO because I also had a software problem with the ssh section. I just installed the ssh server to get that to work. Is there something I need to install for the dashboard?

-Parker

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11121/unable-to-launch-turtlebot_dashboard/) by [ParkerGibbons](https://answers.ros.org/users/978/parkergibbons/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2011-09-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ISO doesn't include the dashboard (as it is a visual tool). Try:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-turtlebot-viz
```

(note, the ISO probably uses diamondback, if using something else, you can change "diamondback" to whichever distro you are using).

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-09-07**:
@ParkerGibbons typically we don't install visualization software on the robots that's why it's not in the ros-diamondback-turtlebot-robot  variant which is included in the ISO. Typically we use "workstation" computer to do visualization which is part of the ros-diamondback-turtlebot-desktop variant